# Is it possible to output to multiple sound devices simultaneiously in Vista / 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I've got a Xonar 2 soundcard which has both SPDIF and analogue outputs, is it possible to tell  7 to play the same audio through both outputs? (it will split out communications).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be possible from Windows' point of view since quite a few hardware cards have independent hardware outputs.

However, this particular behavior can be obtained only with manufacturer's driver.

P.S. Since Windows 7 is technically capable of doing this, there may be some program that can create two separate audio streams from single source...

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't have support for this natively.  It's up to an application to output directly to multiple outputs.

Comment: @Larry: I agree and I thought that I wrote this. He needs "program that can create two separate audio streams from single source".

Comment: The most recent set of drivers does it for me - I now have audio coming out of both the 3.5 for headphones, and SPDIF for Home Theater.